# Increase or decrease the value once the images being pressed

Tags: android

i have a problem where my value wont increase or decrease whenever i pressed the images. i have already tried many ways, still the value retrieved equal to 1 or -1. What can i do to make the the value, lets say 'z', to hold a value. It's like add and subtract. here is the code.

```
public void onClick(View v)
    { 
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.oneImgView:
            images[0].setVisibility(View.GONE);
            images[1].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(images[0].getVisibility() == View.GONE)
            {
                setValue(1);
            }
            display();
            break;
        case R.id.twoImgView:
            images[1].setVisibility(View.GONE);
            images[0].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(images[1].getVisibility() == View.GONE)
            {
                setValue(-1);
            }
            display();
            break;
        case R.id.threeImgView:
            images[2].setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if(images[2].getVisibility() == View.GONE)
            {
                setValue(1);
            }
            images[3].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            display();
            break;
        case R.id.fourImgView:
            images[3].setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            if(images[3].getVisibility() == View.GONE)
            {
                setValue(-1);
            }
            images[2].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            display();
            break;




        }
    }

    public void display()
    {
        int z =+ getValue();

        tView.setText(""+z);
        }


    public int getValue() {
        x=value;
        return x;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Monsur Hossain Ton said you should first put z as a global variable, in fact if you don't put it global it's local and every time you go in display it's a new variable that is create so no link with the past. If you do a global variable.
For this example I set the value of z as 0 to begin with.
By the way you don't need to have this getValue() passing value in a temp variable, you can directly get it from value it will be easier.

```
int z = 0;
public void onClick(View v)
{ 
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.oneImgView:
        images[0].setVisibility(View.GONE);
        images[1].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setValueAndDisplay(1);
        break;
    case R.id.twoImgView:
        images[1].setVisibility(View.GONE);
        images[0].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setValueAndDisplay(-1);
        break;
    case R.id.threeImgView:
        images[2].setVisibility(View.GONE);
        images[3].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setValueAndDisplay(1);
        break;
    case R.id.fourImgView:
        images[3].setVisibility(View.GONE);
        images[2].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setValueAndDisplay(-1);
        break;
    }
}

public void setValueAndDisplay(int value) 
{
    this.value = value;
    display();
}

public void display()
{
    z += value;
    tView.setText(""+z);
}
```

Comment: oh really? can u explain a little bit about the value?

Comment: I don't know if it's really what you want, can you explain more in details what you want ?
this.value keep in memory the value it's a global variable like z normally, so in display, I take this value to add it to z. 
Z += value is same as z = z + value.

Comment: what i want to do is when i click onto one of the images, the output will be one. but if i click again on the same image, the value is zero. another one is that when i click on two images the value would be two

Comment: Hi clad. I already tried it for a couple times. It doesn't work. Logically i think should work too.

Comment: Can you edit your first post and give me all of this class. And can you tell me also what happen when you try the code (tell me the output you get). I just change the code a bit, I deleted all the if in the cases because you don't need to test it if you just set it before. And I put the display fonction in the setValueAndDisplay which will do both action.

Comment: Sorry, i didnt see that you change the display() location. Its work just like i want!! Thank you broooo.

Answer (score 0):

make z global

```
   int z;
   public void display()
   {
            z =+ getValue();

            tView.setText(""+z);
   }
```